# Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql-server

I got this error

> Incorrect syntax near '('

I could not find where is the syntax problem. what is wrong? How to fix it?

```
INSERT INTO Recurring (WO_DespatchName, 
                       FORMAT(start_date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt') AS start_date, 
                       WO_MaidName, WO_CustomerName, WO_Address, 
                       FORMAT (end_date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt') AS end_date,  
                       WO_ContactNumber, WO_Addresss) 
VALUES (@WO_DespatchName, @start_date, 
        @WO_MaidName, @WO_CustomerName, @WO_Address,
        @end_date, @WO_ContactNumber, @WO_Addresss); 

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: Missing context, IMO. Are these `;` valid in your environment-of-choice, where you execute the SQL statements?

Comment: You cannot have things like `FORMAT` and `AS` in the **list of columns** after the `INSERT INTO` statement - **only** column names (no expressions, nothing else)

Comment: try `CAST()` instead of `FORMAT()`

Comment: @Eds, the issue is not with the Format or Cast functions, the users has used the FORMAT function in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suppose to use `FORMAT` into `values`. Try updating your query as below.

```
INSERT INTO Recurring (WO_DespatchName, 
                       start_date, 
                       WO_MaidName, WO_CustomerName, WO_Address, 
                       end_date,  
                       WO_ContactNumber, WO_Addresss) 
VALUES (@WO_DespatchName, 
        FORMAT(@start_date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt'), 
        @WO_MaidName, @WO_CustomerName, @WO_Address,
        FORMAT (@end_date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt'), 
        @WO_ContactNumber, @WO_Addresss); 

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```